# Python: how to call a method coming from an array?

Tags: python, methods, switch-statement

Here's my class which has constants:

```
class Bubble(models.Model):
    GAUCHE = u'0'
    CENTRE = u'1'
    JUSTIFIE = u'2'
    DROITE = u'3'
```

Then in another file, I use `Bulle` like this:

```
drawCustom = {
    Bubble.GAUCHE: canvas.Canvas.drawString,
    Bubble.CENTRE: canvas.Canvas.drawCentredString,
    Bubble.JUSTIFIE: canvas.Canvas.drawAlignedString,
    Bubble.DROITE: canvas.Canvas.drawRightString,
}
```

And in this file, a bit later, I have

```
for bubble in mymodel.bubbles.all():
    # bubble is an instance of the class Bubble
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    # I want to avoid `drawString` and use my array `drawCustom`
    # to make something like:
    #     p.call(drawCustom[bubble](100, 100, "Hello world."))
```

In other words: `p` is a `canvas.Canvas` object, so it can access to all "`drawing`" functions. I would like to avoid a big `if () elif ()` and make something like: `p.call(drawCustom[bubble](100, 100, "Hello world."))`

Here's my code that works but I find it ugly:

```
for b in mymodel.bubbles.all():
    # b is an instance of the class Bubble
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    if b.texte_alignement == Bulle.GAUCHE:
        p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    elif b.texte_alignement == Bulle.CENTRE:
        p.drawCentredString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    elif b.texte_alignement == Bulle.JUSTIFIE:
        p.drawAlignedString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    elif b.texte_alignement == Bulle.DROITE:
        p.drawRightString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
```

Is it possible and if not, what is the way to go in Python?

Comment: And what is `bubble`?

Comment: bubble is an instance of the class Bubble

Comment: I don't see any `Bubble` class

Comment: Have you tried with `drawCustom.get(Bulle.GAUCHE, None)(your_arguments_here)`?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I didn't, because it's my question, and it looks like a good answer, I'll try... but the problem it that those functions are *methods* of a class, and "p" is and *instance* of this class

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Bubble = bulle in french, I've updated my question so it's more "logical"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
drawCustom[bubble](p, 100, 100, "Hello world.")
```

Alternatively, if you store in `drawCustom` method names instead of method objects, you can also do:

```
drawCustom = {
  Bubble.GAUCHE: 'drawString',
  Bubble.CENTRE: 'drawCentredString',
  Bubble.JUSTIFIE: 'drawAlignedString',
  Bubble.DROITE: 'drawRightString',
}
func = getattr(p, drawCustom[bubble])
func(100, 100, "Hello world.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, #1 solution is the way to go.

Comment: @OlivierPons, cool. Note that solution #1 only works if there is only one `Canvas` class. If inheritance is involved, solution #2 is more robust (the right definition of the method will be called)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the keys are right, you can definitely do this. Functions are [first class](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/first-class-everything.html) in Python

So:

```
my_functions = {"function 1": print}

my_functions["function 1"]("Hello, world")
```

works just fine.

I suspect that if you have issues it might be down to the fact that whatever you're using for keys isn't hashable... or you're just not using the right key?..

EDIT: Regarding your edit/comment based on the fact that p is a instance of Canvas, you should just be able to do:

```
drawCustom[bubble](p, 100, 100, "Hello world.")
```

Essentially passing "p" in as the `self` argument (as the methods in your dictionary are not bound to an instance).